# Uncaught Reference Error: google is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I saw a dozen of questions with the same title & the problem. After going through all those problems & making changes in the code, I wasn't able to resolve this issue.

My Google map works fine. But in the console, this error is shown. Can anyone please help me figure out this problem.

I specified JavaScript code inside the head tag

```
 <script>
    function loadScript()
    {
    var myKey = "__API-Key__";
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="+myKey+"&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
    window.onload = loadScript;
    </script>

    <script>

        function initialize()
        {
            var laa=-34.397;
            var lonn= 150.644;
            var mapOptions =
            {
                zoom: 7,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(laa, lonn),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                maxZoom: 8,
                minZoom:2
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('location-canvas'),
                mapOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                draggable: false,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(laa, lonn)
            });

            function bind(eventName)
            {
                google.maps.event.addListener(map, eventName, function ()
                {
                    common();

                });
            }

            bind('zoom_changed');
            bind('center_changed');
            bind('tilesloaded');
            bind('idle');

            function common()
            {
                var bounds = map.getBounds();
                var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
                var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
                var getcentre=bounds.getCenter();
                var ne = map.getBounds().getNorthEast();
                var sw = map.getBounds().getSouthWest();
                var zoom=map.getZoom();
                var centre_lat=getcentre.lat();
                var centre_long=getcentre.lng();
                var myLatlng=new google.maps.LatLng(centre_lat,centre_long);
                var mapProp =
                {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(centre_lat,centre_long),
                    zoom:zoom,
                    maxZoom: 8,
                    minZoom:2,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

            }
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', initialize);
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
```

Inside Body tag:

```
            <div id='location-canvas' style='width:100%;height:500px;'>

            </div>
```

Comment: what is the error on `console`?

Comment: don't worry..it's a fake API key. it doesn't matter

Comment: "ReferenceError: google is not defined" & it points to last two line of js code. Even if I comment it, error remains. @Ravi

Comment: I don't think you need `loadScript()` function, you can do something like this, [Create a Basic Google Map](http://www.w3schools.com/googleAPI/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_map_first). And also if you will call `loadScript` after `initialize()` function, your call will definitely fail. So before calling `google` methods make sure you do link the Maps APi.

Comment: Just remove the 2 last lines of code (addDomListener). You are calling `&callback=initialize` where you load the script, so the initialize function will be fired anyway. If you need to reset some things on window resize, you should be creating another function for that. I don't think calling `initialize` again is what you want to do.

Comment: @Ravi there are cases where you have to load the script this way. No sure if he has to, but it is not *wrong* to do it this way. In any case this is not the issue.

Comment: @MrUpsidown It is not wrong way to load the script, but i think the `ordering` for loading the script does matters, what you say?

Comment: The order the scripts are loaded is not wrong either. He only should remove the window load/resize listeners in order to get rid of the error, which I think is what OP asked for.

Comment: Yes. That's what I asked for. I did it. Error gone. @MrUpsidown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You Don't need to include bellow two lines because you already define a callback function with `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="+myKey+"&sensor=false&callback=initialize`

So either use

`<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="+__API-Key__+"&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Without function call, put it directly on document

or Remove

```
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', initialize);
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

e.g:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="+__API-Key__+"&sensor=false"></script>

<script>

    function initialize()
    {
        var laa=-34.397;
        var lonn= 150.644;
        var mapOptions =
        {
            zoom: 7,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(laa, lonn),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            maxZoom: 8,
            minZoom:2
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('location-canvas'),
            mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            draggable: false,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(laa, lonn)
        });

        function bind(eventName)
        {
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, eventName, function ()
            {
                common();

            });
        }

        bind('zoom_changed');
        bind('center_changed');
        bind('tilesloaded');
        bind('idle');

        function common()
        {
            var bounds = map.getBounds();
            var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
            var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
            var getcentre=bounds.getCenter();
            var ne = map.getBounds().getNorthEast();
            var sw = map.getBounds().getSouthWest();
            var zoom=map.getZoom();
            var centre_lat=getcentre.lat();
            var centre_long=getcentre.lng();
            var myLatlng=new google.maps.LatLng(centre_lat,centre_long);
            var mapProp =
            {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(centre_lat,centre_long),
                zoom:zoom,
                maxZoom: 8,
                minZoom:2,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

        }
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', initialize);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

        <div id='location-canvas' style='width:100%;height:500px;'>

        </div>
```

This should works fine.